# VB.NET checkbox problems

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkbox

Web site in Visual Studio 2010 with VB. I created a GridView with a checkbox column, but my code behind is not recognizing the checked rows. Runs through with no error but never sees a checked row.

```
 <asp:GridView 
    ID="gvwOrderDetails" 
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    runat="server" 
    BackColor="White" 
    BorderColor="#DEDFDE" 
    BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="Black" 
    GridLines="Vertical">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="OrderSelector" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
</asp:GridView>


Protected Sub btnVoid_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnVoid.Click

        Dim atLeastOneRowVoided As Boolean = False
        For Each row As GridViewRow In gvwOrderDetails.Rows

            Dim cb As CheckBox = TryCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("OrderSelector"), CheckBox)

                If cb IsNot Nothing AndAlso cb.Checked Then
                     atLeastOneRowVoided = True
                     Dim orderID As Integer = _
                    Convert.ToInt32(gvwOrderDetails.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Value)
                lbl1.Text &= String.Format( _
                    "This would have voided ProductID {0}<br />", orderID)

            End If
        Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you populate the GridView in the Page.Load event? If so, you need to *not* populate it on a postback: `If Not(Page.IsPostBack) Then PopulateGridView()`.

Comment: I test for IsPostback in Page_Load. If True, I called a sub that populates the GridView.

Comment: That's most likely the wrong way round: usually when the page is first displayed, the data is shown, then when a postback occurs you do *not* want the data reverted to its initial state because that will happen before your button click event is processed. See [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for the order of events.

Comment: When the page first loads, it presents a form to collect user input. Then these parameters are used at PostBack to query the selected records from SQL.   At this point the user selects certain records to process via the Checkbox.  - thanks for the input Andrew